# Complicated MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as follows:

I have a RatingsTable that contains a ratingname and a bit whether it is a positive or negative rating:

```
RatingsTable
----------------------
ratingname  ispositive
----------------------
Good        1
Bad         0
Fun         1
Boring      0
```

And I have a FeedbackTable that contains feedback on things: the person rating, the rating and the thing rated. The feedback can be determined if it's a positive or negative rating based on the RatingsTable.

```
FeedbackTable
---------------------------------
username  thing        ratingname
---------------------------------
Jim       Chicken      Good
Jim       Steak        Bad
Ted       Waterskiing  Fun
Ted       Hiking       Fun
Nancy     Hiking       Boring
```

I am trying to write an efficient MySQL query for the following:

On a page, I want to display the the top 'things' that have the highest proportion of positive ratings. I want to be sure that the items from the feedback table are unique...meaning, that if Jim has rated Chicken Good 20 times...it should only be counted once.  At some point I will want to require a minimum number of ratings (at least 10) to be counted for this page as well.  I'll want to to do the same for highest proportional negative ratings, but I am sure I can tweak the one for positive accordingly.

Comment: What is the PK on FeedbackTable?

Comment: What should happen if Jim rates Chicken as both Good and Bad?

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question and added some column names to your tables. If you want to use different column names from the ones I suggested please feel free to fix it.

Comment: @Mark If Jim rates it as both...he effectively cancels out his vote since this is a proportional vote.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This works perfectly.  Only challenge with this solution is ranking negative feedback now.  Negative feedback is 0, so dividing that by the count doesn't return the right proportion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the "things" in order of proportion of good ratings you can use this query:

```
SELECT thing, SUM(ispositive) / COUNT(*) AS proportion_positive
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT username, thing, ratingname FROM FeedbackTable) T1
JOIN RatingsTable T2
ON T1.ratingname = T2.ratingname
GROUP BY thing
ORDER BY proportion_positive DESC
```

For your example data it returns this:

```
thing        proportion_positive
Chicken      1.0000
Waterskiing  1.0000
Hiking       0.5000
Steak        0.0000
```

To require at least 10 votes before displaying a thing in the results add this line after the `GROUP BY`:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

To get the proportion of negative ratings change `SUM(ispositive)` to `SUM(NOT ispositive)`.

Note: it might be better to add a unique constraint to your voting table instead of selecting only the disctinct values.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This works perfectly. Only challenge with this solution is ranking negative feedback now. Negative feedback is 0, so dividing that by the count doesn't return the right proportion

Comment: @Scott: Try `SUM(NOT ispositive)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM `feedback`
LEFT JOIN `ratings` ON `feedback`.`rating` = `rating`.`label`
ORDER BY `rating`.`value` DESC
GROUP BY `feedback`.`username`
LIMIT 10
```

The summary: join the ratings to your feedback table, but group by the username so you only get one username per result.

Comment: Not at all what the question asks for. Highest proportional positive ratings per food item. It will involve some sort of count of good and bad ratings.

Comment: Well, the end SUM wasn't asked for. It seemed that only a list of the things with high votes was being requested (quote:"  I want to display the the top 'things' "). As seen by the other answer, you can do a sub-query using SUM to append the totals to the final result - elegantly written Mark!

Comment: But if Chicken has 100 Up Votes and 800 down votes you'd need to take that into account!

Comment: Ah - good man! I knew there was a reason for being on here, making sure I don't turn stupid, lol - you're absolutely right